# pdf of exponential Random Variable.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I'm studying for my exam and confronted with a problem.

Suppose we have two RV's $X_1$ and $X_2$ both are exponential. Now we define $Y=X_1+X_2$ and trying to find pdf of $Y$.

I have this equation but I don't know how do we derive the right side from the left side.
$$=\int P( X_2 \leq x - X_1 ).\lambda e^{-\lambda X_1} dx
\\=\int (1-e^{-\lambda(x-X_1)} ).\lambda e^{-\lambda X_1} dx
$$
The complete proof is this:
[Sum of two exponential random variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOIRA.png)

I appreciate for answers in advance and I am sorry if my question is not good enough according to the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That step uses the fact that $X_2$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. The cdf of an exponential distribution is well known and equals $F(y) = 1-\exp(-\lambda y)$. That means $P(X \leq y) = 1-\exp(-\lambda y)$. If you plug in $y=x-X_1$ you obtain the desired result.